# How to auto group monthly data (Stacked column chart) in Power BI presentation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Currently, we created the Power BI report with Excel source and update everyday with incremental changes in DB. I have Bar chart which represents monthly data, using Group option to show data month wise.  With this method, I need to alter the grouping each month and then publish the report.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQZOV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj8i1.png

Is there any option auto group based on month using created Date option Power BI.